# ThemovieDB API unable to access an array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I try to display the actors name of a movie from themoviedb API (with VueJS). I'm unable to access an element in an array, for example only the first (i don't want to dispaly it with a loop).

My request : http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/12208?api_key=f33cd318f5135dba306176c13104506a&append_to_response=credits

And my JavaScript code for displaying an actor (movie is the variable assigned to the response object):

```
movie.credits.cast[0].name
```

It says *movie.credits is undefined*.

Thanks.

Comment: can you update your question with the output for `console.log()` of the response object so we can see its structure

Comment: Please upload the code of your call to the service, the most possible problem is that you are not waiting for the response to be done before using the movie object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to post the code and the error message. Also depending on the method, you are using when your request is successfully an object is returned in the function variable specified by you. example:

```
 var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .then( data()=> {
    //data is the returned object
   let castName = data.movie.credits.cast[0].name
  })
  .catch( error => {
    console.log(error );
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

My HTML Code:

```
<div id="app">     
    {{ movie.credits.cast[0].name }}
</div>
```

JS code:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>     
<script>
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',

data() {
  return {
     movie: ''
  } 
},  

created() 
{   
   axios              
      .get("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/2110?api_key=[MY_KEY]&append_to_response=credits")
      .then(response => (this.movie = response.data.results))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
})
</script>
```

Of course, `[MY_KEY]` is replaced by my real key.